# Shape of passed value indices apply error on creating data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to make a dataframe by extracting comments from a file and their corresponding categories from another. Both have same number of lines of data.

However I'm getting the following error: 
Shape of passed values is (2, 206), indices imply (2, 106)

Below is my code uptil now:

```
from pandas import DataFrame

def build_data_frame():
  rows = []
  index = []
  count=0;
  with open('outlem.txt', 'r') as r:
      info=r.read()
      data_list=info.strip().split('|')

      for data in data_list:
            index.append(count)
            rows.append({'comment':data.strip()})


  with open('classes.txt', 'r') as r:
    for line in r:
        rows.append({'class':line.strip()})

  data_frame = DataFrame(rows, index=index)
  print(data_frame)


build_data_frame()
```

Comment: The length of rows and index are not the same.
You should combine 'class' and 'comment' into a dict and append to rows.

Comment: Okay, guess I had not quite understood the way this works. Was trying this out for first time..Thanks this worked, I read more about it..my concepts are clearer now.